# EF Core behavior in async insert to same table with multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have a Web API, created to insert records into a table. There is a maximum number of records count that it allows (eg. 1000 records). The condition is in the code level, checked before reading from the table and inserting. The method is an async method. The `DbContext` is in default scoped scope.

I found that sometimes, when we send parallel requests to the Web API, to insert, it sometimes skip the condition and insert more than the record count. My question is why is this happening? Is it because the insert requests are aysnc, the context go in to a read- write - read state?

Can it be that since we are sending multiple requests to web API, the `DbContext` read the record count in parallel and identify the record count not exceeded so insert in multiple requests simultaneously.

I notice above specially in a performance test scenario.

Do I need to handle the read and write manually to measure that only one read - write happens at a time?

Any idea how parallel requests are handled by EF Core and IIS Server?

Comment: Could you also include your current code snippet in order to get more clarity.

Comment: Have you tried using `transaction` or any `locking mechanism`?

Comment: Due to lack of proper locking mechanism you are having this problem. Because, without a transaction, each individual operation is not atomic, and there's no guarantee that the database state won't change between the condition check and the actual insert.

Comment: So in order to overcome this issue, you can  configure different isolation level we can use of `SetTransactionIsolationLevel`

Comment: You have concurrency issues. You should consider using a SemaphoreSlim

Comment: This is hard to to answer without seeing code. How can the API insert more records than it sends in one request?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why is this happening? Is it because the insert
> requests are aysnc, the context go in to a read- write - read state?

Not really, when multiple requests are made concurrently, especially in an asynchronous context, the main reasons could be more.

Because it might be due to lack of transaction isolation level as it can break transaction atomicity which occurs when no locking mechanism maintained.

Another important issue could be request concurrency. If the condition check and insert operations are not properly synchronized, multiple asynchronous requests may read the record count concurrently. If these requests are not coordinated, they might all pass the condition check before any of them performs the actual insert.

How to deal with this kind of scenario:

In order to manage request atomicity and concurrency so that there's no dirty reads of uncommitted data modifications encouters during the read write operation, we can use [transaction.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)

If we use transaction in asp.net core while using entity framework, EF automatically creates a savepoint before saving any data. Savepoints are points within a database transaction which may later be rolled back to, if an error occurs or for any other reason.

> Do I need to handle the read and write manually to measure that only
> one read - write happens at a time?

No no need to do that, you can simply use [BeginTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#controlling-transactions) while start your concurren async request. If anything went wrong your transaction will be rollback automatically and there would no inconsistent data read.

> Any idea how parallel requests are handled by EF Core and IIS Server?

You can do that using transaction in entity framework, so no need to depend on IIS pooling. It would be nicer if could share of your existing code so that I it can be investigated in practice.

However, you can try following code to handle concurrent async request:

```
 public async Task ConcurrentParallelOperationAsync()
 {
     using (var transaction = await Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
     {
         try
         {
             /* Note: 
              * You can place our existing code here
              * If possible use  RowVersion which is type of Timestamp in order to maintain concurrency 
              */

             await SaveChangesAsync();
             await transaction.CommitAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             await transaction.RollbackAsync();
             throw;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Note:**  I have use `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted` transaction Isolation level, based on your requirement, you can choose other [isolation mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.isolationlevel?view=net-8.0). Also consider [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#optimistic-concurrency) control for scenarios where locking overhead is undesirable. Please [refer to this official document for more isolation level mechanism.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions)